# C# Windows Forms: Add a HyperLink to a WPF RichTextBox from another Thread (in ElementHost)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, hyperlink, richtextbox

I have a c# Windows Forms project with a WPF RichTextBox (in ElementHost) on the form and want to add a HyperLink to it from another Thread, but i get an TargetInvocationException. This code works if it is executed from the same thread, but i need to execute it from another Thread.

```
Hyperlink hyper = new Hyperlink(new Run("http://google.com"));
hyper.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://google.com");

if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    locParagraph.Inlines.Add(hyper);
}
else
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Background, 
        (System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)(
            () => locParagraph.Inlines.Add(hyper)));
}
```

Comment: Where is the `TargetInvocationException` being thrown? Is it safe to construct and manipulate properties of WPF controls on another thread? I'd `locParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Hyperlink(new Run("http://google.com")){NavigateUri = new Uri("http://google.com")});` in both branches of your `if` statement instead of constructing the `Hyperlink` up front.

Comment: If the command Dispatcher.Invoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Background, 
        (System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)(
            () => locParagraph.Inlines.Add(hyper))); is executed then Application.Run(new Form1()); throws the TargetInvocationException.

Comment: And if you move all your `Hyperlink` construction code so that it runs in the `MethodInvoker` delegate? Same problem?

Comment: It works! Good job! Thank you! Solution:                                         String url = "http://google.com";
                                        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)(() => locParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Hyperlink(new Run(url)) { NavigateUri = new Uri(url) } )));